# How to return multiple values in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, return-value

I want to return multiple values, such as 'firstname' and 'secondname' separately. How can I do this?

I tried to return them as a string, but it's not working:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  pageheader : string = 'text';
  imagepath : string = 'https://3wga6448744j404mpt11pbx4-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Treehouse-Logo-Green-Large.png';
  firstname : string ='Tom';
  secondname : string =' Hopkins';
  getfullName(): string 
  {
      return this.firstname;
      return this.secondname
  }
```

Comment: You can't add multiple `return` statements in a single block, instead you can return object having both values and use it whereever you want!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add multiple return statements in a single block, instead, you can return object having both values and use it wherever you want, for example -

```
getfullName() {
      return {firstName: this.firstname, lastName: this.secondname}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript function returns a single value, so in this case you can return an `object`, `array`, `string` value

**Object**

```
getfullName() {
      return {firstName: this.firstname, lastName: this.secondname}
}
```

**Array**

```
getfullName() {
      return [this.firstname,this.secondname];
}
```

**String**

```
getfullName() {
      return `${this.firstname} ${this.secondname}`;
}
```

Another way you can create a function that returns different name every time it called based on `array`

*Component*

```
  selectedName ='';
  names = ['Tom','Hopkins','Other'];
  index =-1;
  getNames() {
      this.index++;
      if (!this.names[this.index]){
        this.index  = 0
      }
    return this.names[this.index];
  }

  setSelectedName(){
    this.selectedName = this.getNames();
  }
```

*Template*

```
<button (click)="setSelectedName()">Get Name</button> {{selectedName}}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53537642)

Answer (score 0):

If you want full name with your `getFullName()` just use like...

```
getfullName() {
  return `${this.firstname} ${this.secondname}`
}
```